# How to get the group by value as 1 box with comma?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am using SQL version 5.5. I have a problem selecting all values in the group by parentid in the 1 row. May I know how to group by the parentid and show the table results can separate by a comma? For example the result is 1,2,3,4,9

```html
Table name: abc
+----+----------+
| id | parentid |
+----+----------+    
| 1  |   1      |
| 2  |   1      |
| 3  |   2      |
| 4  |   3      |
| 5  |   2      |
| 6  |   4      |
| 7  |   9      |
+----+----------+
```

My SQL group by query like below:

```html
select parentid from abc group by parentid
```

I want the expected result after group by parentid like below the table:

```
    +---------------------+
    |      parentid       |
    +---------------------+    
    |     1,2,3,4,9       |
    +---------------------+
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: if you are doing group by on parentid then the parentId will unique in each how. so you cannot get group_concat on the same column. 
do group_concat and remove group by

Comment: @aRvi Is like this select GROUP_CONCAT (parentid) from abc ?

Comment: @Martheen I cannot use  GROUP_CONCAT in my query. Can you show me how?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done by combining `GROUP_CONCAT` and `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT parentid ORDER BY parentid) FROM abc;
```